# Python-Selenium: Chrome headless setting does not work with "WebDriverWait"

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

The following code passes with real browser but no with headless chrome.

```
 while True:
    try:
        #Explicitly wait
        print("Try4")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "00BC0000008hfCI_listSelect")))
        print("Try5")
        ##Locate the select box
        s = driver.find_element_by_id("00BC0000008hfCI_listSelect")
        ##Unassigned queue
        Select(s).select_by_value("00BC0000008hqG8")
        time.sleep(1)
    except TimeoutException :
        print("Wrong!")
        break
```

The result will be:

```
Try4
Wrong!
```

It seems that the headless chrome can't find the element. It wowrks well with Chrome browser. My Selenium version is 3.14.0.

The HTML will be like:

```
<div class="topNav primaryPalette" id="00BC0000008hfCI_topNav"><div class="controls"><img src="/img/s.gif" alt="Case" class="pageTitleIcon" title="Case">
<select class="title" id="00BC0000008hfCI_listSelect" name="fcf" onchange="ListViewport.instances['00BC0000008hfCI'].showFeedOrListView(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" title="View:"><option value="00BC0000009AFei">All Open Casa Cases</option>
    <option value="00B800000063tb2">All Open Cases</option>
    <option value="00B1A000009ZCok">Channel Upgrade Cases CCLTD</option>
    <option value="00B1A000009VKSg">Channel Upgrade Queue</option>
    <option value="00BC00000099n8S">China team's cases</option>
    <option value="00BC00000097nXg">Delete Queue</option>
    <option value="00BC00000097FPw">Handoff Case Queue</option>
    <option value="00B0y000009vcEI">Maintenance Windows Due Today</option>
    <option value="00B1A000009LY1L">mark r upgrade</option>
    <option value="00B1A000009V2x7">My close case</option>
    <option value="00BC000000976jF">My Open Cases</option>
    <option value="00B0y000009g0J9">My Open Cases - Final Solution Provided</option>
    <option value="00BC0000008hfCI" selected="selected">New Cases Created Today</option>
    <option value="00B0y000009vWOH">New Cases Created Today All</option>
    <option value="00B800000063tb0">Recently Viewed Cases</option>
    <option value="00BC00000099gHm">Stale Case View</option>
    <option value="00BC0000008hqG8">Unassigned Case Queue</option>
    </select><div class="filterLinks" id="00BC0000008hfCI_filterLinks"><a href="/ui/list/FilterEditPage?id=00BC0000008hfCI&amp;retURL=%2F500%3Ffcf%3D00BC0000008hfCI%26rolodexIndex%3D-1%26page%3D1">Clone</a> | <a id="create-new-view" href="/ui/list/FilterEditPage?ftype=t&amp;retURL=%2F500%3Ffcf%3D00BC0000008hfCI%26rolodexIndex%3D-1%26page%3D1">Create New View</a></div><span class="divisionLabel" id="00BC0000008hfCI_divisionLabel"></span><div class="topNavTab" id="00BC0000008hfCI_topNavTab"><div class="toggleButton" id="00BC0000008hfCI_toggleButton"><span class="listToggle chatterListToggle selected"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggleLink" onclick="ListViewport.instances['00BC0000008hfCI'].toggleFeedListView(false)" title="View List - Selected"><span class="toggleIcon listIcon"></span><span class="linkText">List</span></a></span><span class="chatterListToggle chatterToggle clickable" id="ext-gen3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="toggleLink" onclick="ListViewport.instances['00BC0000008hfCI'].toggleFeedListView(true)" title="View Feed"><span class="toggleIcon chatterIcon"></span><span class="linkText">Feed</span></a></span></div><img src="/img/s.gif" alt="" class="printerIconDisabled" id="00BC0000008hfCI_printLinkDisabled" style="display: none" title="Printable view is not available for feeds."><a href="javascript:printWin('/500/x?fcf=00BC0000008hfCI&amp;rolodexIndex=-1&amp;page=1')" id="00BC0000008hfCI_printLink" style="" title="Printable View (New Window)"><img src="/img/s.gif" alt="Printable View (New Window)" class="printerIcon" onblur="this.className = 'printerIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'printerIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'printerIcon';this.className = 'printerIcon';" onmouseover="this.className = 'printerIconOn';this.className = 'printerIconOn';" title="Printable View (New Window)"></a><a href="javascript:openPopupFocusEscapePounds(%27https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00D30000000XsfGEAS/HTAuthProvider?startURL=%252Fapex%252Fhtdoor%253Floc%253Dhelp%2526target%253Dcases_view.htm%2526section%253DCases%2526language%253Den_US%2526release%253D214.17.3%2526instance%253DNA66&amp;site=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.salesforce.com&amp;showSplash=true%27, %27Help%27, 1024, 768, %27width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,directories=no,location=yes,dependant=no%27, false, false);" title="Help for this Page (New Window)"><img src="/img/s.gif" alt="Help for this Page (New Window)" class="helpIcon" title="Help for this Page (New Window)"></a></div><div class="clearingBox"></div></div></div>
```

I tried the two ways but no help.
[chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257870/headless-chrome-with-selenium-can-only-find-ways-to-scroll-non-headless) and [capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370018/selenium-working-with-chrome-but-not-headless-chrome)

Would you please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can _Selenium_ rather _WebDriver_ in conjunction with _WebDriverWait_ locate the _presence of element_ when the element is not present at all?

Comment: @DebanjanB It is part of the code. It should always exists in the page, else it will have timeoutexception and break the loop. I have imported webdriver.

Comment: But I suppose your _locator strategy_ is a bit off. Can you update the question with the relevant HTML?

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated my question. The code actually can work without "headless" setting. I think there may be something related to the headless character..

Answer (score 3):

Adding a real browser user-agent header works for me:

```py
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared and your *code trials* instead of using the *expected-conditions* method `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use the method `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.title[name='fcf'][id$='_listSelect']")))
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='title' and @name='fcf'][contains(@id,'_listSelect')]")))
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for checking the problem. I still get the same error like before. It goes well with the real browser.

Answer (score 0):

How to go headless in Py Selenium using `WebDriverWait` for anyone looking for help.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options). 
WebDriverWait(driver, ...)
```

The `options` keyword used to be `chrome_options`.